# Bootstrap 4 nav menu not working properly on iOS Safari

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress, twitter-bootstrap

The bootstrap 4 nav collapsing menu isn't working properly on iOS Safari for some reason. When pressing the hamburger icon it doesn't expand like usually but displays like that.

Screenshot:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/k0FgT.png

Live site:
REDACTED

Comment: Can you post the code or a working example?

Comment: Added live site link in OP.

Comment: @ZimSystem added.

Comment: just post the html and css for the navbar